# How to fix security issue "CRLF injection/HTTP response splitting (Web Server)"

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-headers, crlf-vulnerability

After security scan from **Acunetix**, i got a medium severity alert **"CRLF injection/HTTP response splitting (Web Server)"**. 
I have filtered all **CR LF** characters from users input in my website. But still it shows same alert.
I **don't understand** how do i solve this issue or **Exact** where is the problem? My PHP version is PHP 7 and i'm using Codeigniter 3.14 framework.
Screenshot given below.
[image]

Comment: Does it say which file or route?

Comment: It doesn't say any specific file or route. [Click to see the screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/nRl7hJp.png)

Comment: What have you tested: just home page / route?

Comment: I scanned it from Acunetix. I just put there my homeurl. Probably it tested all routes. [Take a look my scan summery](http://i.imgur.com/KbOeb3I.png)

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful to you-

> To avoid such HTTP Splitting vulnerabilities parse all user input for
>   CR LF \r\n %0d%0a or any other forms of encoding these or other such
>   malicious characters before using them in any form of HTTP headers.
>   These vulnerabilities can be used to fool their clients and steal
>   authentication information.

Refer- http://www.securiteam.com/securityreviews/5WP0E2KFGK.html

Comment: I have restrict users input and also encode URLs. Still now its not working.